# COM ports don't appear in Cygwin

Tags: ruby, cygwin, serial-port

I'm trying to write a script to automate a file transfer over serial connection to a remote device. My intention is to write the script in Ruby running on Cygwin on my local computer.

To start off with, I need to get serial communication going to the remote device and for that, I assume that I would need to access the serial port via /dev/tty...

When I look in /dev/ in my Cygwin shell I only see the following:

```
$ ls /dev
fd  mqueue  shm  stderr  stdin  stdout
```

I don't see anything like a tty device.

When I check the device manager in Windows (Win7 Pro), it shows 3 com ports. There is one native com port (COM1) and two virtual com ports (COM5, COM6).

For now I'm just trying to get any kind of connectivity going..

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though they don't appear in the listing of `/dev`, they are there anyway. `COM1` is `/dev/ttyS0`, `COM2` is `/dev/ttyS1`, and so on. See [the relevant bit of the manual](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-posixdevices) for the full list of "hidden" devices.

[Upate] Starting with Cygwin 1.7.12, `ls /dev` actually does show all the devices that are present.